# This is about speech synthesis program. I think it seems to be an endless loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-to-speech

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Graph(); print("Training Graph loaded")

# with g.graph.as_default():
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=hp.logdir, save_summaries_secs=60, save_model_secs=0)
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
    while 1:
        for _ in tqdm(range(g.num_batch), total=g.num_batch, ncols=70, leave=False, unit='b'):
            _, gs = sess.run([g.train_op, g.global_step])

            # Write checkpoint files
            if gs % 1000 == 0:
                sv.saver.save(sess, hp.logdir + '/model_gs_{}k'.format(gs//1000))

                # plot the first alignment for logging
                al = sess.run(g.alignments)
                plot_alignment(al[0], gs)

print("Done")
```

The data loading program cannot stop

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop which is `while 1` ... this will run forever. You need a condition that causes a `break` inside that loop somewhere.

Comment: This is the program I downloaded on github, more than 800 stars. I have not changed anything. It is strange that other people's programs can run perfectly. Others did not mention this issue in their comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` statement is missing a `break` rule, either removing the first or adding the second after `plot_alignment`should stop the loop